# PHP: Get parameters from file

Tags: php, get

I am new to PHP so I could need a bit of help. I want to open a text file and read out some variables. But it doesn't put out a value. It is able to read the file. I think the problem is on the getParameter function.

```
<?php
    function getParameter($par, $default = null){
        if (isset($_GET[$par]) && strlen($_GET[$par]))
            return $_GET[$par];
        elseif (isset($_POST[$par]) && strlen($_POST[$par]))
            return $_POST[$par];
        else
            return $default;
    }    
    $file = '/var/www/html/gps.txt';
    $lat = getParameter("latitude");
    $lon = getParameter("longitude");
    $time = getParameter("time");
    $sat = getParameter("satellites");
    $speed = getParameter("speed");
    $course = getParameter("course");
    $person = $lat.",".$lon.",".$time.",".$sat.",".$speed.",".$course."\n";

    echo "
    DATA:\n
    Latitude: ".$lat."\n
    Longitude: ".$lon."\n
    Time: ".$time."\n
    Satellites: ".$sat."\n
    Speed: ".$speed."\n
    Course: ".$course;
?>
```

*Expected output:* Latitude: 49.xxxxx

*Actual output:* Latitude:

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET); var_dump($_POST);` at the top of the page to see what they contain

Comment: i don't see any code that's related to reading from a file at all.

Comment: var_dump($_GET); var_dump($_POST);  outputs: 
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}

Comment: Your script is not reading from any file at all, and your `getParameter` function only tries to find values in $_GET or $_POST. If you don’t _call_ this script with any GET or POST parameters, then of course these arrays are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is wrong. See this change:

```
function getMarkers(){
    $file = '/var/www/html/gps.txt'; 
    $file_lines = file($file);
    $array_lines = [];
    foreach ($file_lines as $line) {
        $array_lines[] = explode(',', $line);
    }
    return $array_lines;
}

$array_lines = getMarkers();

foreach($array_lines as $array_line){
    print_r($array_line);
}
```

Comment: well  I see the difference but it still doesnt work. I get as output:
DATA:
Latitude:xxx
Longitude:pppxxx
Time:uuu
Satellites:iii
Speed:zzz
Course:yyy

In the gps.txt file the values are arranged like so 
lat1,long1,time1,sat1,speed1,course1
(new line)
lat2,long2,time2,sat2,speed2,course2
...

Comment: If in your file you have those lines like a csv, I don't understand why you try to print Post and get variables??  Is all the data that you want to print is in the file gps.txt? In that case, the script is totally wrong and you should read the file instead

Comment: Maybe I didnt make my question understaindable. I want to read the gps coordinates to later show them as markers on a web page with the google maps api. Therefore I have to extract the latitude and longtitude from the list gps.txt

Comment: Ok and why those post and get variables? You dont need that

Comment: Give me one line from your txt

Comment: 40.748440,-73.984629,20130609130551,11,122.5,120

Comment: but basically the first 2 are the most important numbers.

Comment: well first it does output only: "PHP Warning:  explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/                                                  g.php on line 7"

Comment: and if I understaind it correct then it would print out the whole line, but basically I would need the lat and long ... as seperate variables, which I could put into google maps api later. How to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry I missed the second parameter in explode function. That will print the whole line exploding the line into an array

Comment: $array_lines[0] would be the first line. $array_lines[0][0] would be the first line with  lat, $array_lines[0][1] would be the first line with long, $array_lines[1][0].....

Comment: well thank you this actually works, now i have to take it a step further.

Comment: Thats great, dont forget to put your vote in my anwser! :)

Comment: done, but I have one more problem :D 
It does only show the value frome the first line, but I need the values of a whole list

Comment: why cant I do it like this;  var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng($array_lines[0][0],$array_lines[0][1]);

Comment: Yes, try a foreach

Comment: Hey don't forget to vote my anwser!! :) . not this comment. The answer! put it as solved